# change a specific value in yaml file with lot of indentation using python

Tags: python, yaml

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: websitemanager
  namespace: white
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/white/deployments/websitemanager
  generation: 89
  labels:
    app: websitemanager
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: websitemanager
    backup: kube-noah
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '75'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{"deployment.kubernetes.io/revision":"75"},"labels":{"app":"websitemanager","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"websitemanager","backup":"kube-noah"},"name":"websitemanager","namespace":"white","selfLink":"/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/white/deployments/websitemanager"},"spec":{"progressDeadlineSeconds":600,"replicas":4,"revisionHistoryLimit":10,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"websitemanager"}},"strategy":{"rollingUpdate":{"maxSurge":"25%","maxUnavailable":"25%"},"type":"RollingUpdate"},"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.add_error_key":"true","co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.keys_under_root":"true","co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.message_key":"message_key","co.elastic.logs/enabled":"true"},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app":"websitemanager"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"APP","value":"websitemanager"},{"name":"PORT","value":"80"},{"name":"ALLOW_SKIPS","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"ALLOW_SKIPS","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"AWS_REGION","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"AWS_REGION","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"BO_RENDERER_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"BO_RENDERER_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"BO_S3_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"BO_S3_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"CHAT_V3","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"CHAT_V3","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"CMS_RENDERER_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"CMS_RENDERER_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"CRON_EXPRESSION","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"CRON_EXPRESSION","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"CRON_GROUP_SCHEDULE_HOURS","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"CRON_GROUP_SCHEDULE_HOURS","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"CRON_SCHEDULE_HOURS","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"CRON_SCHEDULE_HOURS","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"DYNAMIC_PAGE_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"DYNAMIC_PAGE_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"ENVIRONMENT_BUCKET_ENDPOINT","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"ENVIRONMENT_BUCKET_ENDPOINT","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"ENVIRONMENT_BUCKET_NAME","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"ENVIRONMENT_BUCKET_NAME","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"FIREBASE_KEY","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"FIREBASE_KEY","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"FO_RENDERER_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"FO_RENDERER_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"FO_S3_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"FO_S3_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"GEFEN_ENV","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"GEFEN_ENV","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"LEADS_SQS_DL_QUEUE","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"LEADS_SQS_DL_QUEUE","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"LEADS_SQS_QUEUE","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"LEADS_SQS_QUEUE","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"LOGGLY_INPUT_TOKEN","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"LOGGLY_INPUT_TOKEN","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"LOGGLY_SUBDOMAIN","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"LOGGLY_SUBDOMAIN","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"LOKALISE_API_KEY","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"LOKALISE_API_KEY","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"LOKALISE_PROJECT_ID","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"LOKALISE_PROJECT_ID","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"LP_RENDERER_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"LP_RENDERER_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"MONGO_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"MONGO_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"MONGO_URLS","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"MONGO_URLS","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"NEXTGEN_S3_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"NEXTGEN_S3_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"NODE_ENV","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"NODE_ENV","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"OPERATION_BUCKET_ENV_PART","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"OPERATION_BUCKET_ENV_PART","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"PG_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"PG_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"QUICKSIGHT_ACCESS_KEY_ID","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"QUICKSIGHT_ACCESS_KEY_ID","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"QUICKSIGHT_ACCOUNT_ID","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"QUICKSIGHT_ACCOUNT_ID","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"QUICKSIGHT_SECRET_KEY_ID","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"QUICKSIGHT_SECRET_KEY_ID","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"REDIS_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"REDIS_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"ROLLBAR_API_TOKEN","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"ROLLBAR_API_TOKEN","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"RS_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"RS_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"SES_PASS","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"SES_PASS","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"SES_USER","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"SES_USER","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"STELLAR_REDIS_URL","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"STELLAR_REDIS_URL","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"USE_HTTP_SERVER","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"USE_HTTP_SERVER","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"USE_LEADS_V3","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"USE_LEADS_V3","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"androidBuildName","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"androidBuildName","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"iosAppStoreId","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"iosAppStoreId","name":"env-vars"}}},{"name":"iosBuildName","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"iosBuildName","name":"env-vars"}}}],"image":"gefenonline/websitemanager:develop-111","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","livenessProbe":{"failureThreshold":3,"httpGet":{"path":"/health","port":80,"scheme":"HTTP"},"initialDelaySeconds":5,"periodSeconds":3,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":1},"name":"websitemanager","resources":{"limits":{"memory":"700Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"150m","memory":"400Mi"}},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File"}],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"docker-registry"}],"restartPolicy":"Always","schedulerName":"default-scheduler","securityContext":{},"terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30}}},"status":null}
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: websitemanager
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: websitemanager
      annotations:
        co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.add_error_key: 'true'
        co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.keys_under_root: 'true'
        co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.message_key: message_key
        co.elastic.logs/enabled: 'true'
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: websitemanager
          image: 'gefenonline/websitemanager:develop-111'
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 700Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 150m
              memory: 400Mi
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 3
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-registry
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 89
  replicas: 4
  updatedReplicas: 4
  readyReplicas: 4
  availableReplicas: 4
  conditions:
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2021-08-03T06:34:01Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-08-03T06:33:40Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: ReplicaSet "websitemanager-7cdbcf6488" has successfully progressed.
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2021-08-04T13:57:07Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-08-04T13:57:07Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
```

I have a yaml file and i want to make change in the image key in the file which is under spec-containers by a python script.so far i have got this script but not able to access the key-value-pair and i am quite new to this so can anybody help me on this.i am not able to change the key-value pair in the deployments.yaml file

```
import yaml
with open('deployment.yaml', 'w') as f:
    content = yaml.load(f)
    # for k,v in content.items():
    #     print(k['selector'])
    print(content['spec']['template']['spec']['containers'])
    #doc['spec']['spec']['template']['spec']['containers']['image'] = 'letsencrypt-prod'
    # for k,v in (content['spec']['template']['spec']['containers']):
    #     print(v)
    yaml.dump(content, f)
# with open("deployment.yaml", "w") as f:
#     yaml.dump(content, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing that the level at key `"containers"` is a list, so the zeroth index must be used to get to the `image` key:

```py
import yaml

with open('deployment.yaml', 'r') as fin:
    content = yaml.load(fin, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    content['spec']['template']['spec']['containers'][0]['image'] = "letsencrypt-prod"
with open('deployment2.yaml', 'w') as fout:
    yaml.dump(content, fout)
```

Comment: thanks for the help man